# How to generate custom response for REST API with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, rest

I'm implementing a REST API in Rails 3. We allow for JSON and XML as response formats.

The default `respond_with` works fine as long as one wants only the requested resource to be returned, e.g.:

```
def show
  respond_with User.find(params[:id])
end

GET /users/30.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
  <birthday type="date">2010-01-01</birthday>
  <company-name>Company</company-name>
  <email>email@test.com</email>
  <id type="integer">30</id>
</user>
```

However, I would like to get the following standardized response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <status>
    <success type="boolean">true</success>
  </status>
  <result>
    <user>
      <birthday type="date">2010-01-01</birthday>
      <company-name>Company</company-name>
      <email>email@test.com</email>
      <id type="integer">30</id>
    </user>
  </result>
</response>
```

How can I achieve this result?

I tried the following, using a custom Response class

```
class Response

  STATUS_CODES = {
    :success => 0,
  }

  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON

  attr_accessor :status
  attr_accessor :result

  def initialize(result = nil, status_code = :success)
    @status = {
      :success => (status_code == :success),
    }
    @result = result
  end

  def attributes
    @attributes ||= { 'status' => nil, 'result' => nil }
  end

end
```

and redefining the `respond_with` method in my `ApplicationController`:

```
  def respond_with_with_api_responder(*resources, &block)
    respond_with_without_api_responder(Response.new(resources), &block)
  end

  alias_method_chain :respond_with, :api_responder
```

However, that does not yield the intended result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <status>
    <success type="boolean">true</success>
  </status>
  <result type="array">
    <result>
      <birthday type="date">2010-01-01</birthday>
      <company-name>Company</company-name>
      <email>email@test.com</email>
      <id type="integer">30</id>
    </result>
  </result>
</response>
```

What should be `<user>` is now again `<result>`. This gets even worse when I return an array as the result, then I get even another `<result>` layer. And if I look at the JSON response, it looks almost fine – but notice that there is an array [] too much wrapping the user resource.

```
GET /users/30.json

{"response":{"result":[{"user":{"birthday":"2010-01-01","company_name":"Company","email":"email@test.com"}}],"status":{"success":true}}}
```

Any clue what is going on here? How can I get the desired response format? I also tried looking into writing a custom `Responder` class, but that boiled down to rewriting the `display` method within `ActionController:Responder`, giving me the exact same problems:

```
  def display(resource, given_options={})
    controller.render given_options.merge!(options).merge!(format => Response.new(resource))
  end
```

I believe that the problem is somehow hidden in the serialization code of `ActiveModel`, but I can't seem figure out how I can wrap a resource within a container tag and still achieve that the wrapped resource is being serialized correctly.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did in the end:

1. I got rid of the Response class.
2. I added to_json and to_xml methods to all models:

   ```
   [:to_json, :to_xml].each do |method_name|
     define_method(method_name) do |options = {}|
       options ||= {}
       options[:only] ||= # some filtering
       super(options)
     end
   end
   ```
3. I redefined the respond_with method in my ApplicationController:

   ```
   def api_respond_with(resources, &block)
     default_respond_with do |format|
       format.json { render :json => resources, :skip_types => true, :status => :ok }
       format.xml { render :xml => resources, :skip_types => true, :status => :ok }
     end
   end

   alias_method :default_respond_with, :respond_with
   alias_method :respond_with, :api_respond_with
   ```
4. I wrote a custom middleware with appropriate methods to add the desired wrapping:

   ```
   class StandardizedResponseFilter

     def _call(env)
       status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
       if headers['Content-Type'].include? 'application/json'
         response.body = standardized_json_wrapping(response.body, env)
       elsif headers['Content-Type'].include? 'application/xml'
         response.body = standardized_xml_wrapping(response.body, env)
       end
       [status, headers, response]
     end

   end
   ```

If anyone knows a better approach, feel free to leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Normally what I'd do in this case is override the ActiveModel#to_xml and ActiveModel#to_json methods. The documentation on [#to_xml](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.7/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M004936) describes the possible options. You could probably make your `Request` object inherit from `ActiveModel`, and then override the #to_xml method with a pattern like this:

```
def to_xml(options = {})
  # muck with options such as :only, :except, :methods
  options[:methods] ||= []
  [:status, :result].each { |m| options[:methods] << m }

  super(options)
end
```

In particular I think you'll find options[:methods] useful because it lets you define arbitrary methods that return attributes and get included in the output.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I appreciate that! Indeed, adding to_json and to_xml methods was part of the answer. What I did in addition was write a custom respond_with method to enforce these formats and add a custom middleware that reformats the JSON (or XML) output to add the desired standardized wrapping. I haven't found any other way to get rid of the quirks with the tag naming.

Comment: The super(options) call just returns XML... you can wrap that more easily than in your proposed answer. There is no need to use Rack middleware, content type checking, etc.